# How do I compile and use liboverlay-scrollbar from source?

Tags: programming, compiling, customization, overlay-scrollbars

I'm trying to install and use a patched version of `liboverlay-scrollbar` that matches my personal preferences. I've successfully downloaded [`lp:ayatana-scrollbar`](https://code.launchpad.net/ayatana-scrollbar) and `./autogen.sh; make; sudo make install`*ed* it.

Here's the problem. Taking a look at `ldd /usr/bin/*`, it doesn't look like any applications actually *use* `liboverlay-scrollbar*.so`. And even when I use something like:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib/:/usr/lib/"
export LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=1
gedit
```

The scrollbar-using application I call seems to blithely ignore my `/usr/local/lib` libraries and use the system-installed ayatana scrollbars. My GTK+ libs are stock Ubuntu, so I'm assuming I don't need to patch and recompile the graphical toolkit.

Could anyone post a step-by-step process for installing overlay scrollbars from source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check out an easy tutorial at http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/fixing-a-bug.html

Here is a simple tutorial:

1. Get Ubuntu's overlay scrollbar

   ```
   bzr branch ubuntu:overlay-scrollbar overlay-scrollbar.dev
   cd overlay-scrollbar.dev
   ```
2. Make some modifications
3. Compile and install

   ```
   ./autogen.sh
   make
   sudo make install
   ```
4. Modify a symlink

   ```
   sudo ln -f -s /usr/lib/liboverlay-scrollbar-0.2.so.0 /usr/local/lib/liboverlay-scrollbar-0.2.so.0
   ```
5. (optional) Document the fix and build a package

   ```
   dch -i
   bzr builddeb
   ```

Comment: Note, that steps 3-4 may be skipped, as `bzr builddeb` will create a correct package, which should be installed

Answer (score 5):

I'm not entirely certain, as I'm not very fluent in C, but it seems like the patched GTK that Ubuntu uses to load the scrollbars has been hardcoded to look in `/usr/lib/` only.

[From the patch](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/precise/gtk+2.0/precise/view/head:/debian/patches/100_overlay_scrollbar_loading.patch):

```
+  gchar *flag = (gchar*) g_getenv ("LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR");    
+   
+  /* check if LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR is set to 0 or an empty value   
+     and disable the feature in this case */   
+  if (flag != NULL && (*flag == '\0' || *flag == '0')) 
+    return;    
+   
+  /* default extension library to use for this release */  
+  gchar *path = "/usr/lib/liboverlay-scrollbar-0.2.so.0";  
+   
+  module = g_module_open (path, G_MODULE_BIND_LOCAL);  
+  if (module == NULL)  
+    return;
```

If I were you, I apply my patch to the source package of liboverlay-scrollbar.

Grab the source with bzr: `bzr branch lp:ubuntu/overlay-scrollbar`

Patch the source, edit `debian/changelog` (You can just add a `+myversion1` to the existing version string or add a whole new changelog entry. The key thing is to make sure you have a higher version number the package in the archive). Then run `bzr builddeb` to build the Debian packages.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I'll gladly give you the bounty, but before accepting, would you mind me editting your post to suggest redirecting the `/usr/lib/liboverlayscrollbar*.so.0` symblink instead? That's a much less invasive approach in my opinion. Also, to convert this into a "step by step" guide rather than just resolving my particular roadblock?

Comment: Hello, I've awarded you the bounty for solving my particular problem, but accepted Vadim Rutkovsky for answering the complete question. Thank you very much.